# How to use addScriptTag() with local file path in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to use puppeteer with a local script file.

I get the script file to load when I host the file and use [addScriptTag()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageaddscripttagoptions) with the localhost address. This is not ideal. I need to use the local file directly from the path. The current working directory is /maps in this case. I set the relative path as path in the options of the addScriptTag() function but the code just goes dark on me at this stage. There is no error and no stepping into anything.

```
console.log(`Current directory: ${process.cwd()}`);
// C:\Users\dbauszus\Documents\GitHub\maps
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setContent(jsr.templates('./views/report.html').render(), {waitUntil: 'load'});
    // works with an url to the same file.
    // await page.addScriptTag('http://localhost:3000/maps/js/build/report_bundle.js');
    // path for js file on windows C:\Users\dbauszus\Documents\GitHub\maps\public\js\build\report_bundle.js
    await page.addScriptTag({path: 'public\\js\\build\\report_bundle.js'});
    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Any help will be welcome as I find the puppetteer documentation increasingly frustrating and there aren't (m)any working examples as of now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a version problem. This method was only introduced in the latest update 0.12 from yesterday. I installed puppeteer the day before. Meh!

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/949